# Limit number of uploaded attachments of specific context

Tags: uploads, attachments

I am assigning a custom `_wp_attachment_context` meta to attachments with specific usage. In my case - favicons. I also took advantage of the WP Customizer so my users could upload icons using extended `WP_Customize_Image_Control` control class.

Next thing I was hoping to figure out is how to limit those uploads per context and keep the control's library clean with a max number of uploads allowed. Ultimately I planned old attachments(unless currently used) to be removed or trashed on new attachment upload if limit is exceeded.

Since I am using a customize control to upload/set favicons both added and removed items should be reflected in the "Uploaded" control tab.

```
  api.bind('ready', function() {
    api.control( 'store_favicon', function(control) {
      control.uploader.success = function( attachment ) {
          ...
          api.ImageControl.prototype.success.call( control, attachment );
          ...
    });
  });
```

`ImageControl`'s success is already doing the adding. But I can't figure how to supply my custom `success` method the data if it has to remove items.

Comment: This seems rather straightforward - when attachment is created query and delete older ones (if necessary). Could you maybe break this into specific steps? Like user does X then Y needs to happen and Z is the part you have trouble planning/implementing.

Comment: @Rarst Edited question with more specifics. Thanks.